# ¿De dónde viene la ruta que aparece en el @GET() y en el @PATH()?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

estoy aprendiendo a usar Retrofit para consumir de apis. He visto tutoriales muy buenos pero no veo dónde se explica qué ruta es la que hay dentro del `@GET` y el `@PATH`, es decir, cuando me pongo a crear una aplicación distinta a la del ejemplo no tengo ni idea de qué poner ahí dentro.

```
public interface GithubAPI {
    String ENDPOINT = "https://api.github.com";

    @GET("/users/{user}")
    Call<GithubUser> getUser(@Path("user") String user);

    @GET("users/{user}/repos")
    Call<List<GithubRepo>> getRepos(@Path("user") String user);

}
```

Comment: ¿a qué tutoriales te refieres?, puedes poner, por favor, algunos enlace que ayude a la gente que quiere aprender Retrofit2 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es de la llamada HTTP que se hará para consumir el servicio.

Si abro una conexión HTTP a *https://api.github.com/users/Sjuan76*, esa llamada se pasará al método JSON `getUser`, con el parametro `user` con el valor `Sjuan76`.

Si abro una conexión HTTP a *https://api.github.com/users/Sjuan76/repos*, se invocará al método JSON `getRepos`, con el parametro `user` con el valor `Sjuan76`.

Comment: Gracias @SJuan76 así creo haberlo entendido. Implementaré el ejemplo a ver qué tal.